# sql having clause with aggregate functions

Tags: sql

```
select regno
from examinee
where score>(select avg(score) from examinee)
```

How can I write the above query using 'HAVING' clause?

I've tried writing the below version but it doesn't work(shows empty set)

```
select regno
from examinee
group by score
having score>avg(score);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why you want Having? Having used with group by. You can use as below
`select regno
from examinee
having score>(select avg(score) from examinee)`

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment that you don't fully understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Which doesn't matter, does it? The issue is well explained, OP tells us what he's tried, etc. Only things missing are perhaps an example data set, and a link or two to documentation pages that OP's read to understand the issue.

Comment: you need to place `avg(score)` in your select statement, for starters. You don't need `score>avg(score)` in your `Where` clause, you would place that criteria in your `Having` clause. In this case you wouldn't need a `Where` clause at all.

Comment: Its not a homework assignment.I was practising some questions on sql and when I came across this problem I wrote the 1st version only,but then I thought of writing it using 'HAVING' clause as well.

@Adam J  Thats what I've done in the 2nd version above but it doesn't work with the 'HAVING' clause.......Am I doing something wrong there?I know that I can't use aggregate functions with 'WHERE'    clause as the latter works on columns(unlike former that works on set/group of data).But still can't do it.

Comment: So far you select all examinees with a score higher than avarage. As your query shows there is no need for a HAVING clause. So why do you want to use a HAVING clause? What do you actually want to achieve? If you simply want to practise using HAVING clauses, you'd need a problem first that asks for such a clause. Maybe you would like to give you examples instead of placing a senseless HAVING clause in your existing query?

Comment: You can only use a Having clause with an aggregate funtion is the select statement. You baiscally are passing a boolean statement to the having clause and if that statement evaluates to true, your RDBMS knows to return those records where in which said criteria is true. See my post below for some helpful links to using group by clauses and Having clauses.

Comment: @Jeroen . . . If you understand the question, I encourage you to answer it.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: I just want to know whether this query can be done using a 'HAVING' clause or not?

Answer (score 1):

For your query, the best way seems to declare a variable that will store the average score and then use this variable in your WHERE clause.

```
DECLARE @avgScore INT -- or decimal variable if needed

SET @avgScore = (SELECT AVG(Score) FROM examinee)    

SELECT regno
FROM examinee
WHERE score > @avgScore
```

By doing so you're only querying the database once for the average score instead of querying for each row of the table [examinee].

Answer (score 0):

```
Decrlare @avg Int (255)
Set @avg = (select avg(score)
from examinee
group by regno);

select avg(score), regno
from examinee
group by regno
having avg(score)>@avg;
```

I don't know if you are using T-SQL or MySQL, but the above query is close to what you want. It should set you down the right path. My syntax may be askew since I am used to T-SQL, and it looks like you may be using MySQL. But Here goes:

You need to place avg(score) in your select statement, for starters. You don't need score>avg(score) in your Where clause, you would place that criteria in your Having clause. In this case you wouldn't need a Where clause at all.

See this page for an in depth look at MySQL group by statements: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Or this page for T-SQL Group by statements: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible'ish way I can think of to use a `having` clause for this query is with `exists`:

```
select e.regno
from examinee e
where exists (select 1
              from examinee e2
              having avg(e2.score) < e.score
             );
```

However, it looks weird to have a `having` clause in such a subquery.  There is no `group by` and no correlation clause to the outer query (I'm not counting the `having` as a correlation clause).

Your original query is clearer, in my opinion.